# Exponential product inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I wonder whether it might be possible to demonstrate that if $x_i,y_i \in [0,1]$:

\begin{equation}
\prod_{i}x_i \ge \prod_{i}y_i \implies \prod_{i}e^{x_i} \ge \prod_{i}e^{y_i}
\end{equation}

My intuition tells me that this must be true. So far I couldn't find a proof nor a counter-example. In particular, I wonder whether the inequality holds true if $x_i,y_i \in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is false. Try
$$x_1=\frac{17}{48}, \quad x_2=\frac{3}{8}, \quad y_1=\frac{1}{4}, \quad y_2=\frac{1}{2}.$$
In that case, 
$$x_1+x_2 = \frac{35}{48} < \frac{3}{4} = y_1+y_2,$$
which is equivalent to $e^{x_1}e^{x_2}<e^{y_1}e^{y_2}$, but
$$x_1x_2 = \frac{17}{128} > \frac{1}{8} = y_1y_2.$$

Answer (score 3):

Because $$\prod_{i}e^{x_i} = e^{\sum_i x_i}$$ and the exponential is monotone your implication is equivalent to $$\begin{equation}
\prod_{i}x_i \geq \prod_{i}y_i \implies \sum_{i}x_i \geq \sum_{i}y_i
\end{equation}$$

And this is wrong using $$x_1 = x_2 = \frac{1}{4}$$ and $$y_1 = 1, y_2 = 0$$

Comment: exclude $0,1$ in your choice of $y_i$ and you will it makes sense

Comment: Nice. What if the numbers had to be chosen in the interval (0,1)?

Comment: Still no chance then… choose $y_1$ s.t. $$1 > y_1 > x_1 + x_2 = \frac{1}{2}$$ then obviously $$\sum_{i}x_i < \sum_{i}y_i$$ But because of $y_1 y_2 \to 0$ for $y_2 \to 0$ you will always find a $y_2$ s.t. $$\prod_{i}x_i = x_1x_2 = \frac{1}{16} \geq y_1y_2 = \prod_{i}y_i$$